# Iterative Java merge sort

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying make an iterative version of Merge Sort for an Assignment. I got the Merge sort method from a website, and I worked on the method that is supposed to merge the arrays. However I keep getting an **IndexOutOfBounds Exception**.

I have been working on this for multiple hours and I cannot find the error. Can someone help me find a way to solve this?

So far I have this:

```
public static void MergeSort(int[] array) {
    int current;
    int leftStart;
    int arraySize = array.length - 1;
    for (current = 1; current <= arraySize; current = 2 * current) {
        for (leftStart = 0; leftStart <= arraySize; leftStart += 2 * current) {

            int mid = leftStart + current - 1;
            int right = getMin(leftStart + 2 * current - 1, arraySize);

            mergeArray(array, leftStart, mid, right);
        }

    }

}

public static void mergeArray(int[] array, int left, int mid, int right) {

    int leftArraySize = mid - left + 1;
    int rightArraySize = right - mid;

    int[] leftArray = new int[leftArraySize];
    int[] rightArray = new int[rightArraySize];

    for (int i = 0; i < leftArraySize; i++)
        leftArray[i] = array[left + i];

    for (int i = 0; i < rightArraySize; i++)
        rightArray[i] = array[mid + 1 + i];

    int leftPtr = 0;
    int rightPtr = 0;
    int tempPtr = leftPtr;

    while (leftPtr < leftArraySize && rightPtr < rightArraySize) {

        if (leftArray[leftPtr] <= rightArray[rightPtr])
            array[tempPtr++] = leftArray[leftPtr++];

        else
            array[tempPtr++] = rightArray[rightPtr++];
    }

    while (leftPtr <= left)
        array[tempPtr++] = leftArray[leftPtr++];

    while (rightPtr < right)
        array[tempPtr++] = rightArray[rightPtr++];

}

public static int getMin(int left, int right) {
    if (left <= right) {
        return left;
    } else {
        return right;
    }
}
```

Any sort of help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You should start telling us where exactly the error is located. Which is easy to do, since you know that it's an out of bound error, you can simply use a debugger, or system messages at all points where such an error could possibly happen. And that's your work to do, not ours.

Comment: Try to understand the algorithm and debug code step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code Successfully executed:
Only Small mistake in `mergeArray()` method:

```
array[tempPtr++] = leftArray[leftPtr++];
```

DOn't increment in array... **Replace**

```
 array[tempPtr] = leftArray [leftPtr];
       leftPtr++;
```

**Final code:** Compare my code you will get it.

```
  public static void MergeSort(int[] array) {
 int current;
 int leftStart;
 int arraySize = array.length;
 for (current = 1; current <= arraySize-1; current = 2 * current) {
for (leftStart = 0; leftStart < arraySize-1; leftStart += 2 * current) {

    int mid = leftStart + current - 1;
    int right = getMin(leftStart + 2 * current - 1, arraySize-1);

    mergeArray(array, leftStart, mid, right);
}}}

 static void printArray(int A[])
 { 
 int i;
  for (i=0; i < A.length; i++)
    System.out.println(A[i]);
    }

 static void mergeArray(int array[], int left, int mid, int right)
   {
   int leftArraySize  = mid - left + 1;
int rightArraySize =  right - mid;

      int[] leftArray  = new int[leftArraySize];
int[] rightArray = new int[rightArraySize];

for (int i = 0; i < leftArraySize ; i++)
    leftArray [i] = array[left + i];
for (int j = 0; j < rightArraySize; j++)
    rightArray[j] = array[mid + 1+ j];

    int leftPtr  = 0;
    int rightPtr  = 0;
    int tempPtr  = left;
while (leftPtr < leftArraySize  && rightPtr  < rightArraySize)
{
    if (leftArray [leftPtr ] <= rightArray[rightPtr ])
    {
        array[tempPtr] = leftArray [leftPtr];
       leftPtr++;
    }
    else
    {
        array[tempPtr] = rightArray[rightPtr];
        rightPtr++;
    }
    tempPtr++;
}

 while (leftPtr < leftArraySize )
{
    array[tempPtr++] = leftArray [leftPtr++];

    leftPtr++;
    tempPtr++;
}

while (rightPtr < rightArraySize)
{
    array[tempPtr++] = rightArray[rightPtr++];

    rightPtr++;
    tempPtr++;
}   }

   public static int getMin(int left, int right) {
   if (left <= right) {
return left;
} else {
   return right;
 }}
```

Comment: If you understood above answer accept it @Ronny Pacheco

Comment: That's not an answer. You haven't explained where the original program was wrong, thus nothing is learned. It's not the idea that you provide code that is blindly accepted.

Comment: Thank you. see the code now@Aziuth, array[tempPtr++] = leftArray[leftPtr++];  Incrementing in the array It leads to IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Than you @Ronny Pacheco

Comment: Thank you so much!  @ShivaNandam

Answer (score 1):

Merge sort algorithm is a classical  Divide and Conquer algorithm.

1. Divide the problem  into smaller sub problems
2. Conquer via recursive calls.
3. Combine solutions of sub problems into one for the original problem

The Pseudocode for Merge:

```
C = output[length = n]
A = 1st sorted array[n/2]
B = 2st sorted array[n/2]
i = 1
j = 1
for k = 1 to n
    if A[i] < B[j]
        C[k] = A[i]
        i++
    else B[j]<A[i]
        C[k] = B[j] 
        j++
end (ignores end cases)
```

So your source code problem is this line:

```
array[tempPtr++] = leftArray[leftPtr++];
```

please change to the logic of pseudocode:

```
if (leftArray [leftPtr ] <= rightArray[rightPtr ])
{
    array[tempPtr] = leftArray [leftPtr];
    leftPtr++;
}
else
{
    array[tempPtr] = rightArray[rightPtr];
    rightPtr++;
}
```